# I am something you least expect. What am I?

Tags: riddle

> I am something you least expect.
>
> But when I come, I seem perfect.
>
> You may chuckle, or you may cry,
>
> I always make you wonder why.
>
> In the end, you never knew,
>
> That I’d come out and mess with you.

**I have an extra line to make the riddle more exact**

> Something happens, now you’ve got,
>
> An opposite to your plot.

What am I?

Comment: I like it but notice that your AA BB CC rhyme structure do not work as "expect" and "perfect" do not rhyme.

Comment: I start to wonder if too many other words also fit only too well. But I still think mine is perfect.

Comment: You are an evil *downvote*.

Comment: @lois6b the rhyme between 'expect' and 'perfect' could be described as a half-rhyme, which would be ironic given the meaning of the word 'perfect.'

Comment: You could still argue that expect and perfect would rhyme with a heavy accent.

Comment: I saw the title and immediately thought "The Spanish Inquisition" (from Monty Python.)

Comment: @LevelRiverSt you are not alone :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are

> a chance or opportunity

I am something you least expect.

> We cannot expect many chances in our life.

But when I come, I seem perfect.

> A chance needs a decision. A good decision seems perfect.

You may chuckle, or you may cry

> We are happy if we used the chance. If we miss it, we are unhappy.

I always make you wonder why.

> A chance creates a feeling of amazement and admiration.

In the end, you never knew,
That I’d come out and mess with you.

> We even did't know that we got chances in our life.

Something happens, now you’ve got

> Everyone will get a chance if something will happen in their life.

An opposite to your plot

> A chance may change our plans or events in our life.

Comment: Good job, correct answer!!!

Comment: I had "An idea". Oh well. Well done.

Answer (score 14):

Are you a

> **plot twist** ?

I am something you least expect. But when I come, I seem perfect.

> Unexpected ending, perfectly written

You may chuckle, or you may cry, I always make you wonder why.

> Sometimes sad and sometimes happy, but always surprising

In the end, you never knew, That I’d come out and mess with you.

> Plot twists often arrive at the end of the movie, and mess with your mind

Comment: Nope, but Nice answer.

Comment: Allow me to translate OP's response: *Nice answer, but not what* ***I*** *was thinking.*

Answer (score 8):

Are you the

> **Spanish Inquisition** ?

I am something you least expect. But when I come, I seem perfect.

> Nobody expects Spanish Inquisition!

You may chuckle, or you may cry, I always make you wonder why.

> That's funny, but inquisition will have the last laugh. And sometimes you don't know why you've got their attention.

In the end, you never knew, That I’d come out and mess with you.

> Inquisition will surely mess with you. [image: You didn't expect that!]

Comment: +1 This is clearly the only correct answer!

Answer (score 7):

Are you...

> The answer to this puzzle?

I am something you least expect.

> Nobody expects the answer to be the actual answer

But when I come, I seem perfect.

> The answer being the answer is a perfect solution

You may chuckle, or you may cry,

> We may chuckle if we appreciate the twist, or cry if we get stuck solving the puzzle

I always make you wonder why.

> Wonder why we didn't think of it before

In the end, you never knew,
That I’d come out and mess with you.

> The puzzle is messing with everyone trying to solve it

Something happens, now you’ve got,
An opposite to your plot.

> The hint does not match the solution, making it the opposite of a hint

Comment: i am just about to post this answer!

Answer (score 6):

This is kind of a broad riddle. I'm pretty sure this isn't the answer but I hope you enjoyed my way of thinking:

Are you:

> Chicken wings in BQQ sauce

I am something you least expect.

> Never expect somebody to cook this for me.

But when I come, I seem perfect.

> Chicken wings in BQQ sauce are heaven and always welcome.

You may chuckle, or you may cry,

> I'll cry when somebody makes me these. I'll chuckle when I take the first bite.

I always make you wonder why.

> They always make me wonder why they are so darn good.

In the end, you never knew,

> I never knew why they are so good.

That I’d come out and mess with you.

> Well you know, on the toilet nr 2. It can get messy when you use BQQ sauce.

Comment: -1 for the use of codeblock on something that isn't code. Italicise or use simple quotation marks, please.

Comment: I just copy-pasted it from the question and wrote my answers in between

Answer (score 3):

You are

> A pleasant surprise

I am something you least expect.

> Of course, nobody expects a surprise

I am something you least expect.

> They usually are, for a short time..

You may chuckle, or you may cry,

> Tears of joy, chuckling if it is more subtle

I always make you wonder why.

> People wonder why anyone would give them a surprise unless it is their birthday or something

In the end, you never knew,

That I’d come out and mess with you.

> Yeah, surprises do mess with our plans sometimes

Comment: wow 5 secs before Maria

Comment: No, but it works rather well, as the meaning is similar. But there's a bit of a twist that, I think, makes my answer better.

Answer (score 3):

You might be a:

> Baby.

I am something you least expect

> Even parents trying to conceive are pleasantly surprised to learn that their efforts have borne fruit.

But when I come, I seem perfect

> Most of the time, parents think that their own new-born child is perfect.

You may chuckle, or you may cry

> New-born babies can make their parents very happy, but also sad if unfortunately struck with some disease.

I always make you wonder why

> Any parents who haven't looked at their kid at some point and wondered "Why???" please raise your hands.

In the end you never knew/ That I'd come out and mess with you

> Going to assume its more of 'never knew... mess with you', since all parents know the kid is going to come out some day! But yeah kids are usually a much bigger mess than expected.

Answer (score 1):

It could be:

> A surprise

I am something you least expect.

> A surprise is something you do not expect

But when I come, I seem perfect.

> A good surprise seems perfect

You may chuckle, or you may cry,

> Of joy from the surprise

I always make you wonder why.

> You wonder why would someone surprise you

In the end, you never knew,

> You never knew (suspected) you will be surprised (otherwise it won't be a surprise).

That I’d come out and mess with you.

> A bad surprise can "mess with you".

Comment: I beat you to that by 4 seconds!!!

Comment: @Sid you sure did. :) But you skipped a line - that is why. :P

Comment: My internet connection was down...

Comment: No, but I really like your answer

Comment: -1 for the use of codeblock on something that isn't code. Italicise or use simple quotation marks, please.

Comment: @Nij It is hard to edit it from a phone. For the record, copy- pasting it from the original post renders it like that. Also, on puzzling this is not codeblock, but preformatted text.

Comment: No, copy-pasting doesn't do that. You have to manually add the spaces on every line to make it do so, there is no automation for it.

Comment: @Nij actually it does. What I did is simply copy the text from the question and then paste it. If you don't believe me - try it yourself. The preview is visible under the box you are writing in, so you can see it without actually posting an answer. Still, it is simply "preformatted text" here - also visible when you hover over the {} icon.

Comment: **I did.** And, as with every other time before, there was no codeblock, no preformattimg indicator, and nothing remotely similar to either the markdown you included nor the resulting display.

Comment: @Nij Ok, once I get home, I will make a video to show you.  This will happen in 6 hours or so. If the browser matters, I am using Firefox.

Comment: @Nij PS. The browser obviously matters. Just tried with IE and Chrome - doesn't work in either. But it does with Firefox. For the record, both actions - copying and pasting, are performed in the same browser.

Answer (score 1):

Are you...

> **a Miracle** ?

I am something you least expect. But when I come, I seem perfect.

> Nobody expects miracle to happen.. When it does, it feels perfect.

You may chuckle, or you may cry, I always make you wonder why.

> Miracles make you cry if they're really helping you out. Same for the question why, you'll never know why the miracle happened but it did.

In the end, you never knew, That I’d come out and mess with you.

> You can never know when the miracle is coming.

My first answer on this site ;)

Answer (score -1):

I feel like there's a better answer:

> **Love**

I am something you least expect.

> Love often happens out of nowhere.

But when I come, I seem perfect.

> Overwhelmingly so.

You may chuckle, or you may cry,

> It can make you happy or it can make you sad.

I always make you wonder why.

> Sometimes it makes no sense at all.

In the end, you never knew,

That I’d come out and mess with you.

> It can turn your whole world upside down.

Something happens, now you’ve got,

An opposite to your plot.

> Life is your plot. Your partner is your opposite.

Comment: Downvote? Wow. So mean... Can you at least post your reason as "heartless" :/